# Display Search Query in URL PHP

Tags: php, search

I have a textbox that allows users to search my website.

```
<form method="post" action="">    
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Upon the user clicking the "Search" button, how do create the following URL, and append the contents of the search box to end, whilst adding "_" in replace of any spaces?:

## http://www.mysite.co.uk/find/**this_is_my_search**

Also, if somebody edits the search query in the URL, how do I update the search textbox to reflect this change, so the box contains the following

**this is my search.**

Comment: why would you do that? Do you really think that user will be editing search query in browser address field and replace all spaces to underscores?

Answer (score 0):

You can change action URL with JavaScript before submit event.
You can Use onSubmit event or use jquery
`$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).attr('action', $('#search').val().replace(' ', '_'))
})`

Comment: I'm looking to do this using PHP only, not JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle that url using you 404 page. You can use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get that path. For instance you could do this in your custom 404 page:

```
<?php
    if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/find/") == 0) //If url is yoursite.co.uk/find/
    {
        $searchterm = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        //Search for $searchterm
        //Print the results
    }
    else
    {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved several ways.

**Javascript**

See StarLight's answer. It's simple and does the job, but you need to check for illegal URL-characters.

**PHP redirect**

Example: Set form action to 'search.php'.

```
<?php
$urlstr = urlencode(str_replace(' ', '_', $_GET['search']));
header("Location: http://www.mysite.co.uk/find/$urlstr");
exit;
?>
```

To update the textbox you need the following code on the page showing the search box.

```
<?php
// First get $urlstr from url.
$searchstr = str_replace('_', ' ', urldecode($urlstr));
$textboxvalue = (empty($searchstr)) ? 'Search' : $searchstr;
?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="<?=$textboxvalue?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change form method to get.. And also if you're using code igniter or other framworks you should be able to code like

```
  $search = Uri:segment(2);
  echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="'.$search.'" />';
```

Comment: What do i need to do in the .htaccess file though, to make the url friendly: http://www.mysite.co.uk/find/this_is_my_search

Comment: You can use ; <ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
</ifModule> . your url simly should look like index.php/find/blablabla .. So in index.php you should route find controller with search param. But it's another job.. Just use codeigniter framework it's easy and handle all this stuf for you